# How to use a JPanel as JButton?

Tags: java, swing

I must use a swing-ui designer tool to create my UI, that only supports graphically editing JPanels. Those panels (they basically contain complex button designs) to work like a JButton. I cannot use anything other than JPanel as base class of these panels (UI editor limitation).

What is the most generic solution to do this?

- Create a custom button that uses the panel's draw method instead of
  it's own?
- Create a base-panel class that reimplements the whole
  button?
- Another more elegant solution?

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use this designer :). Why you must use it?

Comment: Our development guidelines define that we have to use the UI designer for any graphical swing stuff :-/

Comment: There are very many designers which supports all swing components. For example NetBeans IDE. Also Eclipse has a plugin for the graphical design of UI. But IMHO it's a bad idea to use designers (at least when you learn swing).

Comment: Does NetBeans allow you to create custom buttons (using the ui designer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick demo, to show you how you could use borders to simulate a button.

The demo also reacts to mouse and key events :

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class JPanelButton extends JPanel {

    Border raisedetched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);
    Border loweredetched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final JPanelButton panel = new JPanelButton();
        panel.raiseBorder();

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
                panel.lowerBorder();

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {
                panel.raiseBorder();

            }

        });

        panel.setFocusable(true); // you need this or the panel won't get the key events
        panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {
                panel.lowerBorder();

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e) {
                panel.raiseBorder();

            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void raiseBorder() {

        setBorder(raisedetched);
    }

    public void lowerBorder() {

        setBorder(loweredetched);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `MouseListener`.

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }

});
```

If this answer isn't specific enough, leave a comment and I'll give you more explanation.

Comment: Mouse listener only covers mouse interaction, what if you press the button by keyboard? What about the graphical "pressed" effect?

Comment: for keyboard, add [KeyboardListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for graphical effect you can implement the graphics used for JButton which doesn't make sense. Writing GUI in Java Swing is easy. You can write it without the designer tool.

Comment: @xenteros you should at least set the appropriate border for the panel, in other case user cannot understand that it's a button..

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I don't care about the design as it's primary oppinion based. I have answered the technical part of the question.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy `Those panels (they basically contain complex button designs) to work like a JButton.`